# How to remove tag from SelectQuery object

Tags: hooks, database

I process `SelectQuery` object using `hook_query_TAG_after()` or `hook_query_alter()`.

I want to remove 'mytag' tag, which has been added as `$query->addTag('mytag')` somewhere else. Apparently, neither `SelectQuery`, nor `QueryAlterableInterface` has appropriate interface method.

Is there any means (besides `SelectQuery` subclassing) that I can use to remove a tag?

The reason may be the following (thanks Clive for asking):

I want to make a decision based on (expected) record set size inside `hook_query_TAG_after()`

I could do `$countQuery = $query->countQuery(); $total = $countQuery->execute()->fetchField()`

But, the cloned query will have same tag as original one and `execute()` will invoke the same hook ad infinitum.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? Could you not just ignore it based on exactly the same condition that would have to be satisfied in order to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I still can not find a way to remove a tag from query, but I found solution for my case of count query. The idea is to use another tag to stop endless recursion:

```
function mymodule_query_mytag_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {

  if ($query->hasTag('counted')) {
    return;
  }

  // Prepare count query
  $countQuery = $query->countQuery();
  $countQuery->addTag('counted'); // Abort hook recursion

  $tables =& $countQuery->getTables(); // Query may have sub-queries

  foreach ($tables as &$table) { // Tag all subqueries
    if ($table['table'] instanceof SelectQueryInterface) {
      $table['table']->addTag('counted'); // Abort hook recursion
    }
  }

  $total = $countQuery->execute()->fetchField(); // execute() will initiate recursion!

 // Rest of processing

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
    $new_query = clone($db_query);
    unset($new_query->alterTags['search_api_db_facets_base']);
    if (empty($new_query->alterTags)) {
      unset($new_query->alterTags);
    }
    $search_api_current_entities = $new_query->execute()->fetchAll();
```